# Navigation issues with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently having issues navigating from one page to another on my flutter application. I am really new to Flutter, as this is my first application, and this site has helped me before so I'm hoping it will help me again.

The code below in the "//Drawer List" section is having issues with the "Navigator.push" within "onTap" which I want to implement for multiple ListTiles. The code runs great in my Android Emulator, but when I click the ListTile in the drawer I get this in the terminal:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a
descendant of a Navigator widget.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Navigator.of.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2553:9)
#1      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2560:6)
#2      Navigator.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2016:22)
#3      MyApp.build.<anonymous closure> (package:bit/main.dart:58:27)
#4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
#5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:198:24)
#6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
#7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
#8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:267:7)
#9      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:157:27)
#10     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:443:20)
#11     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:419:22)
#12     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:322:11)
#13     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
#14     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
#15     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
#16     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
#20     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:170:10)
#21     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:331:7)
#22     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)

Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer:
  TapGestureRecognizer#d5f04
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

After clicking it a second time a second error comes up and then repeats.

```
Another exception was thrown: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a
Navigator.
```

I tried messing with a few solutions I found online, but all of them seemed to give me the same error so I was hoping someone could help me fix/find what I am missing in the below code. Thank you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var scaffold = Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test App'),
      ),
// Body Home Page Beginning
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
              child: const Center(
        child: Text('Hello'),
      ))),
// Body Home Page End
      drawer: Drawer(
        // Drawer Beginning
        child: ListView(
          children: [
// Drawer Header
            DrawerHeader(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: Stack(
                children: const [
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        radius: 50.0,
                      )),
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Text(
                        'Username',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                        ),
                      ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
// Drawer List
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Profile'),
              subtitle: const Text('Account Information'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const About()),
                );
              },
              trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded),
            ),
            const ListTile(
              title: Text('Education'),
              subtitle: Text('Homeschool Education Material & Quizzes'),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded),
            ),
            const ListTile(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
// Drawer End
    );
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: scaffold,
    );
  }
}

class About extends StatelessWidget {
  const About({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );
  }
}

class SinTracker extends StatelessWidget {
  const SinTracker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

All code is stored in "main.dart" file.

Comment: Is the code you provided, in a single file?

Comment: Yes, this is all stored in the "main.dart" file and the terminal responses in VS Code.

Comment: This code works without any issues. I tried on Android Emulator, iOS Simulator and Chrome

Comment: why are you using `MaterialApp()` twice?

Comment: @AbhishekDoshi Thank you for trying on all those options, however I may have been unclear in my post as I test the code more. It doesn't seem to be an error that the code is experiencing, but an "exception" that doesn't allow it to navigate to the other pages, is there a way to get the exceptions to disappear and allow it to switch pages?

Comment: @xrayian I am very new to flutter code, first application, I thought that was required I'll go through and fix that.

Comment: @Jared I didn't even got any exceptions 

Comment: @AbhishekDoshi well thank you, because I just restarted my entire computer, VS Code, and the Emulator and that seemed to do the trick. I didn't edit the code or anything, just needed to restart I guess. My apologies for wasting your time, but thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code and my emulator just needed a reboot/restart. Someone checked it in the comments and I am simply providing an anwser to get it off the questions list.